# Linear regression using standard deviations as regressors?

Tags: regression, standard-deviation

I am reviewing a study in which standard deviations (SDs) of an X variable, calculated for each individual in the study (measures on each individual were replicated 4 times), are used as predictors of a Y variable. They do not observe a significant correlation between Y and the SDs of X and they conclude by saying that it is not necessary to consider the variability among replicates of the same individual and, therefore, they can work with average values​​.

Does that make sense?

Comment: If it's possible to quote the passage in question that might help: sometimes nuances get lost in the retelling.

Comment: What would your test statistic be if you are not regressing on data, but on estimates of the variability of data?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't undestand what they are doing. Here what I understood:
You have a $y_{i}$ response, and a coavariate $x_{it}$, where $i = 1, 2, .. n$ is the individual measure and $t=1, 2, 3, 4$ is the time dimension. Here, the $y$ didn't vary by time, is that right?

Is that correct? If so, it seems that they calculated sd in $x$ for each i, so they got $n$ sds. The they looked at cor(y,sd(x)), and since it was low, they concluded that it would be ok to use the mean value of x.

This doesn't sound good to me. First, with only 4 observations, sample standard deviation will have only 3 degrees of freadom. Second, the fact that the variabiliy within each individual doesn't correlate with y is expected, since y doesn't vary. But it may be that is the first observation, for example, that matters, not the mean.